# Получение ячейки по API

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Собственно задача передавать в CRM-систему информацию о номере ячейки по товару для быстрого сбора заказа (сборщик работает в CRM, не в Мой склад).

Прямым путем, как я понимаю, эту информацию мы получить не сможем. В запросе:
[https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/community/posts/360000884527-Как-по-API-1-1-получить-данные-в-какой-ячейке-находится-товар-](https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/community/posts/360000884527-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-API-1-1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80-)

Есть информация:
"обходной путь, хоть и костлявый через доп.поля у документов"

Скажите, как это сделать? Нам нужен любой способ получить по API информацию о том, в каких ячейках хранится товар.

Comment: Складских ячеек так и не появилось.

Answer (score 0):

Тут только совет уйти от сборки через crm.
Все таки crm больше для менеджера. Если учесть, что у Вас есть отдельный человек(или несколько) занимающийся сборкой, то лучшим решением будет выделить ему отдельную учетку в МС с определенными правами.
Клиент, товар и деньги это разные люди в организации.

Comment: Безусловно, это было первой мыслью. Но у клиента один сотрудник занимается и обслуживанием клиентов, и отпуском заказом. По сути он стоит в магазине на кассе и должен провести все операции в CRM, а также отдать товар (понять где он: в какой ячейке).

Comment: второй сверху ответ очень приглянулся https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/community/posts/360001920747-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5